# Terminal process stopped when MacBook Pro was closed and opened

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I am installing files from a website using `wget` in Terminal and when I closed and reopened my Mac, the download stopped. Is there a way to start it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you installed `wget` from MacPorts or HomeBrew (it doesn't come preinstalled on macOS), you can resume a download using the `-c` or `--continue` flag.

```
$ wget -c http://foo.bar
$ wget --continue http://foo.bar
```